# How i should use sed for delete specific strings and allow duplicate with more characters?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i had generate a list of file, and this had 17417 lines like :

```
./usr
./usr/share
./usr/share/mime-info
./usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.mime
./usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.keys
./usr/share/appdata
./usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-writer.appdata.xml
./usr/share/appdata/org.libreoffice7.0.kde.metainfo.xml
./usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-draw.appdata.xml
./usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-impress.appdata.xml
./usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-base.appdata.xml
./usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-calc.appdata.xml
./usr/share/applications
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-xsltfilter.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-writer.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-base.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-math.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-startcenter.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-calc.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-draw.desktop
./usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-impress.desktop
./usr/share/icons
./usr/share/icons/gnome
./usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16
./usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/mimetypes
./usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/mimetypes/libreoffice7.0-oasis-formula.png
```

The thing is i want to delete the lines like :

```
./usr
./usr/share
./usr/share/mime-info
./usr/share/appdata
./usr/share/applications
./usr/share/icons
./usr/share/icons/gnome
./usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16
./usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/mimetypes
```

and the "." at the start, for the result must be like :

```
/usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.mime
/usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.keys
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-writer.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/org.libreoffice7.0.kde.metainfo.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-draw.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-impress.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-base.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-calc.appdata.xml
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-xsltfilter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-writer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-base.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-math.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-startcenter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-calc.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-draw.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-impress.desktop
/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/mimetypes/libreoffice7.0-oasis-formula.png
```

This is possible using sed ? or is more practical using another tool

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete everything that was a directory from your listing -- without any way of knowing what was a directory to begin with? Or do you only want to keep lines that have a `.something` extension or `-something` pattern in the last part?  Or do you want to delete lines starting with `'.'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete the line(s) which is included other
pathname(s), would you please try:

```
sort -r list.txt | awk '                # sort the list in the reverse order
{
    sub("^\\.", "")                     # remove leading dot
    s = prev; sub("/[^/]+$", "", s)     # remove the rightmost slash and following characters
    if (s != $0) print                  # if s != $0, it means $0 is not a substring of the previous line
    prev = $0                           # keep $0 for the next line
}'
```

Result:

```
/usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.mime
/usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.keys
/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/mimetypes/libreoffice7.0-oasis-formula.png
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-xsltfilter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-writer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-startcenter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-math.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-impress.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-draw.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-calc.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-base.desktop
/usr/share/appdata/org.libreoffice7.0.kde.metainfo.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-writer.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-impress.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-draw.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-calc.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-base.appdata.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

With your list in the filename `list`, you could do:

```
sed -n 's/^[.]//;/\/.*[._].*$/p' list
```

Where:

- `sed -n` suppresses printing of pattern-space; then
- `s/^[.]//` is the substitution form that simply removes the first character `'.'` from each line; then
- `/\/.*[._].*$/p` matches line that contain a `'.'` or `'_'` (optional) after the last `'/'` with `p` causing that line to be printed.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -n 's/^[.]//;/\/.*[._].*$/p' list
/usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.mime
/usr/share/mime-info/libreoffice7.0.keys
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-writer.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/org.libreoffice7.0.kde.metainfo.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-draw.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-impress.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-base.appdata.xml
/usr/share/appdata/libreoffice7.0-calc.appdata.xml
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-xsltfilter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-writer.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-base.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-math.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-startcenter.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-calc.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-draw.desktop
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice7.0-impress.desktop
/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/mimetypes/libreoffice7.0-oasis-formula.png
```

Note, without GNU `sed` that allows chaining of expressions with `';'` you would need:

```
sed -n -e 's/^[.]//' -e '/\/.*[._].*$/p' list
```